# ion-radio default checked *ngfor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, radio-button, ion-radio-group

I'm new to ionic-framework. My task is next, I want,  When the component is opened, the radio button should be checked  default. I want one to be checked.Thanks in advance

enter image description here

[Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZesFA.png)

[file typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyVWL.png)

[tools.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1Rh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really grasped the meaning of your component, but I would say that initializing your "radioList" variable to 0 should be sufficient.

Also, it would be better to go by the id of your ColorValueObjInterface.
it would give, in your .ts

```
radioList:number = colorValueObj[0]?.id || 0;
```

And your .html

```
...
<ion-radio type="radio" [value]="item.id" name...></ion-radio>
...
```

And please, use the code sample btn to post your code